# How to solve "PayPalHereSDK" error "_xmlDocDumpFormatMemoryEnc", referenced from:

Tags: xcode, magnetic-cards, paypal-here

Hi Friends i am implementing "PayPalHereSDK" and i facing the issue "_xmlDocDumpFormatMemoryEnc", referenced from:" kindly guide me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the solution is very simple,

Go to Project->Target->Build Phase->Link Binary With Libraries->Click add->"libxml2.tbd" that's it